# how to add data separately in cell of tableview separately

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm having three buttons on table view cell and have to show some text on label below it but when i'm clicking on button and selecting text it shows in all row and if second button clicks data of first label get blank so is their any way to fill data seprately to cell of table view

Comment: how about showing some code and screen shot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is you have to test for indexPath to see if that cell will display or not what you want. And keep in mind that cell are reused so you have also to remove content from cells or use different cell identifiers for each type of cell.